# Matrix Exponentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to create a method for taking matrix exponentials $a,b$ where a,b are arbitrary matrices.

I have the following idea:

If we let:

$$(e^b)^a = e^{ba}$$

Where the product isn't commutative then it becomes possible to rewrite the generic case of:

$$a^b = e^{\ln(a)b}$$

And thus have now defined matrix products for pairs of matrices that can be multiplied.

Does this make sense? Are there any inconsistencies, what is the functional analog of this (since matrices are just linear functions).

Comment: I've fixed up your math formatting; please, take a look at my edit to see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. On one hand, matrix logarithm does not always exist. If, say, $a=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$, you cannot take logarithm and hence $a^b$ is undefined. On the other hand, matrix logarithm is not unique. For $a=I_2$, you may take $\ln(a)$ as $p=\pmatrix{0&-2\pi\\ 2\pi&0}$ or $q=\pmatrix{0&-\pi\\ 4\pi&0}$, but in general, $pb$ and $qb$ have very different eigenvalues and $e^{pb}\ne e^{qb}$. Hence $a^b$ is not well-defined.